# print multiple parameters in c

Tags: c, char, printf

I have this function takes more than one char parameters.how to print each of them and add a '\n' at the end of each char?

```
void printAndSave(char* msg,...)
{
     //printing single one.
    //printf("Log:%s\n",msg);
    //saveToLog(msg);

   //how to print all of them?

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you will need to change the signature of `printAndSave()` to specify the number of `char*` arguments being passed. For example:

```
void printAndSave(const unsigned int arg_count, ...)
{
    unsigned int i;
    char* val;
    va_list vl;

    va_start(vl,arg_count);
    for (i=0;i<arg_count;i++)
    {
        val=va_arg(vl,char*);
        printf ("%s\n",val);
    }
    va_end(vl);
}
```

Comment: first parameter doesn't always have to be count; if OP's first argument (the `char* msg`) e.g. holds something like a format string which can also be used to deduce the number of parameters

Comment: @nyarlathotep, ok. But it is necessary for the function to be informed of the number of arguments to be processed.

Answer (score 1):

Look for example at the end of this [page](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter9/stdarg.html). You should easily adapt it for your problem ;) Please note you have to know the type of them.